# How to change wordpress project name?

Tags: wordpress, rename

I want to change wordpress project name from myblog to webblog.
How to do it?
I have posted some pages and posts, just I want to change dir name to webblog.
When I change it, I can't access as admin.

```
http://localhost/webblog/wp_admin
```

This url doen't work, 404 error happens.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your WordPress configuration.

Go to Settings -> General and adjust "Home URL" and "Blog URL". Make sure those are not overwritten elsewhere.

Furthermore you have to make sure your .htaccess file is configured properly afterwards.

Everything you have to know is documented on the codex very well.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL